# how to specify path to Gemfile.lock during bundle install with capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm, capistrano, bundler

My directory structure is as follows:

```
application/
  tmp/
  rails_code/Capfile
  rails_code/config/deploy.rb
  rails_code/Gemfile
  rails_code/Gemfile.lock
  non_rails_code/
```

I am using capistrano to deploy the application code, but when i run cap deploy, then it fails to install gems using bundler, because it expects the Gemfile.lock to be in the application directory, whereas it is actually in the application/rails_code directory.

How can i specify the correct location of the Gemfile?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is configurable, do:

```
set :bundle_gemfile,  "rails_code/Gemfile"
```

Comment: This helped me too when Capistrano was setting an invalid Gemfile, e.g.: failed: "sh -c 'cd /home/rails/alpineanswers-staging/releases/v0.87 && bundle install --gemfile /home/rails/alpineanswers-staging/releases/v0.87/home/rails/alpineanswers-staging/releases/v0.87/Gemfile --path /home/rails/alpineanswers-staging/shared/bundle --deployment --without development test'"